# Custom Segue Involving Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, segue, uistoryboard

I have run into a problem trying to create a custom segue. I have copied the following code from a tutorial:

```
import UIKit

class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform()
    {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        src.present(dst, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        )
    }
}
```

However, I think I have diagnosed the problem which is that I have created a segue to a view controller embedded in a navigation controller. How might I adjust my code to fix this problem?

Call:

```
@IBAction func sendToSignUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: NameFile.Segues.segueToSignUpP1, sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? you just mentioned there is one, did not say what it is...

Comment: I am segueing to a nav controller. In other words, the "destination" is a navigation controller rather than the view controller embedded inside of it.

Comment: Is the target controller set to be the navigation controller or the controller that you want?  Can you add the call to this segue? This would help...

Comment: It's set to be the navigation controller. And what do you mean by call?

Comment: Can you post where do you call the perform segue with your custom segue?

Comment: If you want it to segue to the view controller, the view controller has to be the destination. If you want it to go to the nav controller, the nav controller has to be your destination

Comment: I have included the call

Comment: I want to get to the view controller, but the problem is that it is embedded in a nav controller

Comment: So the destination is a nav controller not the actual view controller